# How do I configure my Hotmail to use a different address when sending?

Tags: email, outlook

When I send an email from my Hotmail account on the website, I can configure it to use one of my other addresses (e.g. pobox.com).  I would like to set up my Windows Phone 7.5 (Lumia 710) to do this.  Is it possible?

*Addendum* My question is specific to using a mail forwarding service such as pobox.com which forwards to hotmail.com.  I want to configure my Hotmail client on Windows Phone so that it sends emails with my @pobox.com address on the From line.

If this can't be set up with the OOB Hotmail client, perhaps it can be done by setting up a custom email client, using "advanced settings".

If there is something about Hotmail which makes this impossible, then I'll just leave, and find another inbox provider (maybe gmx.com).  The only reason I am using Hotmail right now, is that I had hope that Hotmail/ActiveSync would work better than a non-Microsoft inbox with IMAP.  Maybe this isn't true.

Any insights out there?

Comment: Not possible on windows phone 7.5

Comment: Forwarding to another address is the only worksaround I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I configured by Windows Phone to work with my Pobox.com address, as follows:

### Configure my Pobox.com inbox to forward to one of the free publicly available IMAP services.

I chose GMX instead of Gmail, because GMX allows you to disable spam filtering completely.  This is desirable because Pobox.com already has good, configurable spam filtering.

### Configure my Windows Phone.

The phone can both (1) be an IMAP client to GMX, and (2) send outgoing messages via SMTP using Pobox.com's servers.  This setup for outgoing email is desirable, because I trust Pobox.com to do all the right things, to prevent my emails from getting blocked by other people's spam filters.

I set this up using the control panel at this path through the phone UI:  *Settings > email+accounts > add an account > advanced settings.*

When done this way, the email client on the phone has one slighting annoying limitation. The IMAP client is only allowed to sync with the server every 15 minutes.  For some reason, more frequent sync is not given as an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like the website, BUT there is a workaround.

You can link as many of your inboxes as you'd like, so you can see and respond to all of the email from those accounts from the same inbox. When sending mail the phone will even ask which account to use. All you need to do is have both accounts setup on the phone.

I know what you are going to say :)  *"But I don't want the email to come done from the other account"* Yes, that would be annoying. Just tell the other account to only download content manually. You can change this is your `Settings` > `Email + Accounts` > `[your account]`. Under "Download new content" select "Manually". It will only download when you press the Sync button in the email app, but you can still send.

Linking your inboxes

#### To link inboxes

1. From Start, press an email account that you want to link to another account.
2. Press More [...] > Link inboxes.
3. In the Other inboxes list, press any inboxes you want to link to this one. As you press them, they'll move into the This inbox list.
4. Press Rename linked inbox, delete the existing name, type a new name, then press Done. The newly linked inbox Tile will appear on Start.

#### To unlink inboxes

1. From Start, press a linked email account.
2. Press More [...] > Linked inboxes.
3. In the This inbox list, press each account you want to unlink and then press Unlink. The inbox moves to the Other inboxes list.

Comment: I can't see how ths is a solution to the question asked.  I have a linked Inbox for GMail, Hotmail and Office 365, and when I reply any email from any of them, they are sent from the corresponding address.  The linked Inbox is like a virtual folder as far as display is concerned, but they still act indepedently.  It's is not even possible to move emails between the accounts.  I need to do that through Outlook on the desktop.

Comment: I answered his question, but provided a workaround for now. When sending a new mail you will be asked what account to use.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't sound like a workaround to the question I'm actually asking.  But thanks for the info.